# Simulate flat button mouse MouseDown and MouseOver

Tags: c#, user-interface

I have a Windows Forms application with some buttons for the F keys. When you place the mouse over the buttons the get grey, and when you click they get a slightly lighyer grey. I would like to mimic that behaviour with F key keystrokes... how would you do it?

Comment: Highly related with this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304714/simulating-a-click-with-the-keyboard-in-windows-forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I implemented the button changing the background:

```
class FunctionButton : Button
{
    private Color m_colorOver;
    private bool m_isPressed;

    public FunctionButton() : base()
    {
        m_isPressed = false;
    }

    protected override void OnGotFocus(EventArgs e)
    {
        OnMouseEnter(null);
        base.OnGotFocus(e);
    }

    protected override void OnLostFocus(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!m_isPressed)
        {
            OnMouseLeave(null);
        }

        base.OnLostFocus(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Focused && !m_isPressed)
        {
            base.OnMouseLeave(e);
        }
    }

    public void FunctionKeyPressed()
    {
        // Handle just the first event
        if (!m_isPressed)
        {
            m_isPressed = true;
            m_colorOver = FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor;
            FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor;

            OnMouseEnter(null);
            PerformClick();    
        }
    }

    public void FunctionKeyReleased()
    {
        m_isPressed = false;
        FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = m_colorOver;

        if (Focused)
        {
            OnMouseEnter(null);
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnMouseLeave(null);
        }
    }
}
```

It is not the most clean way but it works fine. I would like more examples doing this with a cleaner and more elegant style.

Answer (score 3):

Set the Form's `KeyPreview` property to `true`, handle the `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` events, track which function key(s) are pressed, and call the `Invalidate` method on the button for each key the went down or up.

Then, handle the button's `Paint` event, and, if its key is down, use the [`ButtonRenderer` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.buttonrenderer.aspx) to draw the button as if it were pressed.

Comment: I will try something like that. Thanks!

Comment: I doesn't work because you can't render Flat buttons with ButtonRenderer :-o

Answer (score 1):

Use Button.PerformClick().

Comment: That calls the functionality, but the graphical state of the button won't change.

Answer (score 0):

[SetCapture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/ms646262(VS.85).aspx) and ReleaseCapture might work.