# Simulating a click with the keyboard in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I want to make a button that acts with the keyboard as with the mouse. I'm implementing it this way:

```
class FunctionButton : System.Windows.Forms.Button
{
    public FunctionButton() : base() { }

    protected override void OnGotFocus(EventArgs e)
    {
        OnMouseEnter(null);
        base.OnGotFocus(e);
    }

    protected override void OnLostFocus(EventArgs e)
    {
        OnMouseLeave(null);
        base.OnLostFocus(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Focused)
        {
            base.OnMouseLeave(e);
        }
    }

    public void FunctionKeyPressed()
    {
        OnMouseDown(new MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.Left,1,0,0,0));
        PerformClick();
    }

    public void FunctionKeyReleased()
    {
        if (Focused)
        {
            OnMouseEnter(null);
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnMouseLeave(null);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how to get a valid click position for this button to generate de event

```
OnMouseDown(new MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.Left,1,X,Y,0));
```

How can I do this? Is the better way to implement this kind of button?

Comment: Highlt related with this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299157/simulate-flat-button-mouse-mousedown-and-mouseover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I implemented the button changing the background:

```
class FunctionButton : Button
{
    private Color m_colorOver;
    private bool m_isPressed;

    public FunctionButton() : base()
    {
        m_isPressed = false;
    }

    protected override void OnGotFocus(EventArgs e)
    {
        OnMouseEnter(null);
        base.OnGotFocus(e);
    }

    protected override void OnLostFocus(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!m_isPressed)
        {
            OnMouseLeave(null);
        }

        base.OnLostFocus(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Focused && !m_isPressed)
        {
            base.OnMouseLeave(e);
        }
    }

    public void FunctionKeyPressed()
    {
        // Handle just the first event
        if (!m_isPressed)
        {
            m_isPressed = true;
            m_colorOver = FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor;
            FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor;

            OnMouseEnter(null);
            PerformClick();    
        }
    }

    public void FunctionKeyReleased()
    {
        m_isPressed = false;
        FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = m_colorOver;

        if (Focused)
        {
            OnMouseEnter(null);
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnMouseLeave(null);
        }
    }
}
```

It is not the most clean way but it works fine. I would like more examples doing this with a cleaner and more elegant style.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly, you are creating a control that will show a button that the user can click, and that will also be bound to a function key that should invoke the same command.

I would believe that the simplest (although perhaps a slightly "hacky") way to do this, is to create a `UserControl`, add a [`MenuStrip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menustrip.aspx) control to your user control, add a [`ToolStripMenuItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripmenuitem.aspx) to the `MenuStrip` control and set up a `Click` event handler, and set the `Visible` property of the `MenuStrip` to `false`. Also add a button to the user control, and set up a `Click` event handler for that one. Have both event handlers call some method to perform the action, and finally create a `ShortcutKeys` property reflecting the [`ShortcutKeys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripmenuitem.shortcutkeys.aspx) property of the menu item:

```
public partial class FunctionButton : UserControl
{
    public FunctionButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PerformCommand();            
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PerformCommand();
    }

    private void PerformCommand()
    {
        OnClick(EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public Keys ShortcutKeys
    {
        get
        {
            return _menuItem.ShortcutKeys;
        }
        set
        {
            _menuItem.ShortcutKeys = value;
        }
    }
}
```

In my sample the click event handlers will simply raise the `Click` event of the user control, so that the consumer can attach an event handler to that event and act on it.